# Definition of glass transition

Tags: definition, phase-transition, glass

I am getting confused about the definition of a "glass transition".

1. I read for example that it can be a transition from a rubber state to a brittle state in polymers. In this case therefore I would consider that as a "amorphous solid $\rightarrow$ amorphous solid" transition, since liquid polymers are not involved.
2. I read also that supercooled liquids can undergo a glassy transition, for example water can enter a glassy state. In this sense I would call it a "liquid $\rightarrow$ amorphous solid" transition.

Are these both  "glass transitions" ?

I read that "glass transitions" are accompanied by small structural changes that cannot easily explain the difference (order of magnitutes) of physical properties between the two states. I can understand this problem in case (1), but in case (2) a liquid and an amorphous material to me are clearly very different (in one atoms diffuse, in the other not). So this makes me wonder if a transition of type (2) is still considered a glass transition or not.

Comment: If the 'amorphous solid' is a configurationally frozen liquid, then it is a glass transition - the viscosity changes smoothly until the material is 'solid'. There are amorphous solids that undergo first-order phase transitions to the liquid (and first-order phase transitions to the crystalline solid). Rubber to brittle is similar - the viscosity changes smoothly from one to the other, and likely from 'rubber' to 'liquid' as well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is a "configurationally frozen liquid" ? For me amorphous solids are materials where atoms individually do not diffuse (like in crystals) but do not possess the long range order  typical of crystals.

Comment: the viscosity changes until the material is "solid" --> for me an "amorphous solid' is already 'solid'. Could you explain better ?

Comment: well, there are degrees of being solid, as measured by the viscosity - being 'solid' can be on a continuum from molten glass to a window pane. But, if by x-rays you can't tell a difference in local structure, the window pane is an amorphous solid (and a configurationally frozen liquid). Compare with silicon: liquid silicon is an 8- to 12-fold coordinated metallic liquid; crystal silicon is a 4-fold coordinated diamond cubic solid; amorphous silicon is a 4-fold coordinated solid without long-range order.

Comment: *[...] a continuum from molten glass to a window pane."* Surely molten glass is just molten? All liquids are amorphous, those below their $T_g$ are (amorphous) solids?

Comment: @Jon Custer So we can say that a "glass transition" is whenever we have a discontinuity in viscosity that is not detected by structural changes ( in the sense that the static structure factor does not change ) ? This would encompass both case 1 and 2. In this sense the silicon (crystal) -> silicon (amorphous) is a glass transition because the coordination number does not change but a possible transition silicon (liquid) -> silicon (amorphous) would not be a glass transition because the coordination number changes. Am I understanding correctly what you say ?

Comment: https://pslc.ws/macrog/tg.htm you can read about polymers here. The concepts can be ported to other glasses as well.

Comment: @Thomas - for amorphous vs crystal silicon, while the coordination number does not change, there is a large difference in the diffraction pattern - there is no smooth continuous transition from the amorphous to crystal.

Comment: @Jon Custer do you want to say that sylicon(crystal)->sylicon(amorphous) IS NOT than a glass transition ?

Comment: ( and that sylicon(amorphous) IS NOT a glass ? )

Comment: @Thomas - those are absolutely correct. the amorphous-to-crystal silicon transition has an associated enthalpy (so first order), and amorphous silicon is not structurally related to the liquid.

Comment: Related (soda lime glass): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/773962/226902