# What is the latent heat of melting for a everyday soda lime glass

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, phase-transition, glass

This science direct article
https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/chemistry/soda-lime-glass
States a particular type of glass (the most common one) and it's properties i was unable to find the latent heat energy required to melt it
=>Just out of curiosity if I had to melt like 1 ton of it to recycle into somthing else then how much energy (in joules) would it require

Comment: I thought that "soda lime glass" was a glass full of some lime-flavoured soda beverage. If you experienced the same: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soda%E2%80%93lime_glass

Answer (score 8):

The reason you cannot find a latent heat for glass is because it is an amorphous solid and does not show a sharp solid to liquid transition like crystalline solids. Instead of melting it undergoes a [glass transition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glass_transition) over a wide range of temperature, and that means we cannot define a latent heat of fusion.

However some Googling found [this PDF](https://cyberleninka.org/article/n/1305427.pdf), and it states:

> In the industry of soda-lime glass it is considered a value of $2550$ kJ to bring $1$ kg of soda - lime glass to a working temperature.

The reference it gives for this is: *Kovacec M, Polipovic A, Stefanic N. Impact of glass cullet on the consumption of energy and environment in the production of glass packaging material. Recent Researches in Chemistry, Biology, Environment and Culture. Monteux, Switzerland, 2011.*

So to melt your ton ($\approx 1000\textrm{kg}$) of glass would take about $2.55$ GJ.

Comment: So you can't separate that energy into one part that raises the temperature and another part that changes the phase by watching the temperature go up and then watching the phase change happen as you heat the glass. But could you do it by calculating how much the kinetic energy of the molecules change and how much potential energy is required to break bonds and such in the melted state?

Comment: @mmesser314 Yes. The glass gets gradually softer as it gets hotter and there is no sudden liquid-solid transition. So some of the heat is going into raising the temperature and some is going into making the glass softer. It's as though the specific and latent heats have been mixed together.